# C# Advanced use of OrderBy and ThenBy

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda

I've mostly got this together, but I'm having one minor issue with my sorting.

I want to sort a list by a few specific words, there may be pairs with this list, an example would be Compiled Box and Box. Those Items I want paired together. A word does not have to be preceded by some other word like "Sale"

Example:

```cs
List<string> wordList = new List<string> { "Compiled Box", "Office Order", "Shop Order",
"Box", "Compiled Thing", "Thing", "Sale" };

List<String> newList = wordList
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Contains("Shop Order"))
    .ThenBy(item => item.Contains("Office Order"))
    .ThenBy(item => item.Replace("Compiled", ""))
    .ThenBy(item => item).ToList();
```

The Output I have is:

```
Shop Order
Compiled Box
Compiled Thing
Box
Sale
Thing
Office Order
```

The Output I want is:

```
Shop Order
Office Order
Compiled Box
Box
Sale
Compiled Thing
Thing
```

I get why I'm getting the output I'm getting, but I'm not positive about how to achieve the desired result here? Thank you

Comment: Can you explain your order _with words_? And also, do you ever want to sort other things than those 6 values? What are other possible values, and how would they be sorted in the list?

Comment: The list may or may not contain the words "Shop Order" and "Office Order". Words in list may or may not be preceded by the word "Compiled" So there could be some other word like "Drawing" (that would be at place [4] in the list I would like to create) It's a very weird sorting, hopefully that clarifies a little.

Comment: This is not the order I'm getting when I run your code. I get your order when I replace the first `ThenBy` with `ThenByDescending`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
List<String> newList = wordList
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Contains("Shop Order"))
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.Contains("Office Order"))
    .ThenBy(item => item.Replace("Compiled ", ""))
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.Contains("Compiled "))
    .ThenBy(item => item)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @plusss Mark it as the answer if it helped.